# Use a collection as object inputs in Animation nodes

Tags: node-editor, objects, animation-nodes, groups, collections

i;m trying to use animation nodes for the first time. I've made a sub program which does what it's supposed to (scale objects up as a sweeper object goes past them in the X axis) , but How can i make it do this for all objects in a collection instead of having to put an object input for each object i want to affect?

Something like " for each object in Collection, set it as input for Subprogram"

I have hundreds or maybe thousands of objects i want this to apply to so its really not practical to add them all one by one. 
[image: My current setup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *Loop Subprogram* to do "for each *something* in *somehing*":

[image]

Comment: A huge amount of thanks, that worked perfectly, i just "changed objects from group" to "collection Info" because i'm in 2.8 and it doesn't seem to have groups here.

Comment: Hi, hopefully this question and answer is still live because i'm really struggling with the answer!  I have tried every way possible to pass the Collection list length into the subprogram - how do you get the 'Iterations' input on the Invoke Subprogram node?  Without it, i can't see how you get the loop to address each object in the Collection.  Any help will save my sanity . . . .!!

Comment: @StephenSamuels add Invoke Subprogram node, click New Subprogram and choose type: Loop. The node should have the iterations input. Then you go to the subprogram node and add a new parametre of type Object Group. If this does not work, what version of AN are you using?

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I've been messing around with animation nodes for about 2 years and that's the first time i've understood how to achieve an iteration input!  (i could have saved myself a lot of hair tearing if i'd asked sooner!).  What i have been doing is adding a loop node, defining the iterators and parameters and then creating an invoke node.  This then comes with inputs to match the loop node - an iteration input therefore missing.  By creating loop and invoke nodes together - before defining inputs - gets me precisely where i wanted to be.  Thank you Jaroslav, you've done it!