# How to convert equations to work with Blender and animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes, mathematics

I have an equation that I'm trying to animate in Blender 2.79b

The equation is.
$$y=e^{{{\log \left(1-x^{{\it (S*T)}}\right)}\over{{\it (S*T)}}}}$$

Where:

```
T={1.12,0.96}  % The variable **T** would be a slider in blender*
={15.3039,10.3612,7.9153,6.3793,5.3019,4.4955,3.8656,3.3584,2.9405,2.5903,2.2926,2.0367,1.8146,1.6204,1.4496,1.2983,1.1638,1.04377,.93622,.83959,.75256,.67401,.603,.53871,.48045,.42762,.37969,.33619,.29673,.26094,.22852,.19917,.17265,.14874,.12722,.10791,.090664,.075316,.061733,.049793,.039383,.030399,.0227475,.0163414,.0111008,.0069525,.0038286,.0016664,.0004081}
```

My thought process / how I created it in Octave / Matlab

**Step 1.**
Evaluate the equation for several values of **S** and **T** to see if it works and plot.  See image below.
[image: Step 1 test formula]

**Step 2.**
Evaluate the equation for all the given values of **S** and **T** and plot. See image below.
[image: Step 2 image]

**Step 3.** 
Duplicate object created in Step 2 so I can rotate them at different time values to create / animate different Moire patterns.  See image below.
[image: Step 3 image]

I'm trying to reproduce it using Blender / Animation nodes. But I'm not sure how to correctly loop through all the different values of **'S'**. Then duplicate that object for rotation.
See current Blender file / image below.
[image: Animation math nodes]

The goal is to create different equations and animate them to create different animated Moire patterns.  Something like the example animation below but using different patterns created with equations.

[image: Example animated Moire gif]

[image]

I tried following 3DSinghVFX answer but I had some issues with his/her **step 3** some of the options are either missing or other nodes are being added for me anyone know why?  See animation below of what happens (I circled the things that are different in 3DSinghVFX answer in my animation when I tried to create them) I'm running Blender 2.79b.

[image: Issues I ran into]

Comment: You need a subprogram to process a list of items, in this case list of integers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131817/7777

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very easy to do, here I'm showing for a simple equation, y = sin(W*x), where W is a parameter and x is an independent variable.

**Step-1**
Create two lists, one for the parameter (parameter-1 is as W in this case), and other for variable x. Make a loop using the parameter-1 list as iterator and x-values as an input list,
[image]

**Step-2**
Make a group node (Equation) for y = sin(W*x) equation which later helps you to easily replace with another equation if you want. I'm converting x and resultant y list into a vector list and as output from the group node.
[image]

**Step-3** 
Then add this group node into the Parameter Loop which we created in the step-1, and you view the output vector with 3D viewer Node.
[image]

**Step-4**
Last step to convert group node vectors to splines (curves) using "Splines Form Points" node and then as output from the parameter loop. Use the Curve Object Output node to convert splines to a curve object which you can render.
[image]

Comment: Thanks!! for the help I ran into a couple problems with `your step-3 answer`.  Nodes are either automatically being added for me or options are missing.  I updated my question to add an animation to show what it's doing.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: 1) Parameter-1 is a Float value but not a Float List, you are connecting float list to float that is why list node pops up. 2) Click on "+ New Generator Output" of Parameters Loop node and search for Vector List, then connect the Vector List of Group Node.

Comment: Thanks!!!  that did it :-)